# HTML 5 mobile app and storing authentication data

Tags: html, mobile

I'm building a HTML 5 mobile app for my software.

I've had a look around a a few questions similar to mine but all seem to have different answers depending on their needs. I'm not sure of the best solution.

Is it ok to submit a form using AJAX to authenticate a username and password in a mobile app? I'd be using HTTPS.

And then use sessionStorage to store a returned token?

I'd also like to store an API key using sessionStorage so I can pull data from the API.

Would sessionStorage be secure enough to store the API key as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those interested, this is what I've decided to do:

1. Use AJAX over HTTPS to send log in details to server
2. Server validates and sends back a token that expires after a certain amount of time
3. The token is stored in sessionStorage and every time I make a request to load something from the server, it checks that token is valid

Answer (score 2):

First of all, local and session storage are not encrypted, period. They are just like a cookie, you need to do the encryption/decryption yourself. So no, don't store your key in plain text in session storage. As for the other question, I barely have any idea what you are talking about...

Comment: Thanks Angela. That makes sense. I've reworded the other question which hopefully makes more sense: "Is it ok to submit a form using AJAX to authenticate a username and password in a mobile app? I'd be using HTTPS."

Comment: Ajax login are done all the time, as long as they are done correctly, like using HTTPS :)